# Problem with editing simultaneously

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

I just tried editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401086/how-to-pass-value-from-one-class-to-other-class-in-java) for formatting and tags as the OP was editing it him/herself, adding the stack trace. As I saved my edit, it was registered as deleting the stack trace. Obviously that edit got rejected, but I never technically deleted the stack trace, it wasn't there when I started editing.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just unlucky timing.
Usually, when you're editing a post, you will get a notification if someone else applies a edit before you did.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I must have missed the notification.