# Simultaneous editing (exact same timestamp) - no warning when overwriting other edit

Tags: discussion

The edit history for https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33522279/revisions shows two simultaneous edits (right down to the second) of the question (one by me). Upon saving, I didn't get any warning related to this - in effect, I accidentally deleted everything the other edit had done.

This sounds similar to [Problem with editing simultaneously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261498/problem-with-editing-simultaneously) , but I'm not 100% sure whether it's exactly the same problem.

Shouldn't the backend reject my edit or at least warn me that I'm going to overwrite someone else's changes?

Comment: The post you link to indicates there's a provision to warn about other edits but the issue appears to be that the warning here did not have a chance to get delivered because the two edits got submitted too close in time.

Comment: You didn't really delete it of course, its still right there in the revisions :) You overruled it.

Comment: @Louis: So, in other words, there's a race condition somewhere in the Stack Exchange code.  Should we retag with [bug]?  It's certainly *possible* to get this right... just hand out magic cookies when you start editing something, and store them temporarily in the database.  You can then use transactional isolation to ensure one edit happens and the other is rejected, regardless of how close together they are.

Comment: @Kevin Then you have additional weird and even less expected effects (who wins was determined before either hits "submit"), and still the same problem. Unless SO deliveres a popup warning that someone else is editing, which then requires some way for the two editors to communicate to deconflict the issue, or just auto-diff/merges everything instead of accepting actual revisions, etc. the current solution -- where both edits *exist* but the one received first is *overruled* -- is the most practical, so long as people *can find the edits*.

Comment: @zxq9: You misunderstood.  The other cookies are only invalidated when someone hits submit.  This is just like the status quo, but without the race condition.

Comment: @Kevin The way it works now both commits are accepted, the latest one takes precedence, overriding the other -- and both are in history. In what is essentially a wiki system *this is much better* than mysteriously rejecting the arbitrarily invalidated receipt. They are *both* valid and neither should be discarded. Consider: Abe opens edit, as does Brian. Abe goes to significant effort to fix layout/add citations/references/etc. while Brian spends a lot of effort adding totally new information. They commit at the same time. Should Abe's be rejected or Brian's? The answer is "neither".

Comment: @zxq9: List that as an answer and see how many downvotes it gets.

Comment: @Kevin Challenge accepted. I await your (now almost certain) downvote.

Comment: [related if not duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307671/why-is-there-no-concurrency-control-and-real-time-synchronization-for-editing-qu)

Comment: @Tensibai Wow, nice find. It is basically this page all over again.

Comment: @zxq9 And there's an open  [feature Request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166861/can-we-get-a-better-conflict-resolution-to-edits-vs-suggested-edits) on metaSE too

Answer (score 8):

We need real [edit conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Edit_conflict), not these half-assed "The edit was rejected because it conflicted with another" Community rejections we have currently.  Conflicts should be handled *not* by just rejecting the edit, but by showing a screen with all this information to the editor.  Specifically, this includes the edit(s) which conflicted with the new edit, the new edit itself, and a brief explanation of what happened.  The editing interface is opened automatically and the user is allowed to manually merge their changes in.  This is far better than allowing new edits to randomly trample old edits, as zxq9 is suggesting.

This is accomplished by storing the revision ID of the current version in an invisible form field when you open the editing interface.  That revision ID is checked against the latest version as part of the edit-submitting process.  If it does not match, we have a conflict.  Obviously, this must be done in the same database transaction as the edit itself, or else we have all kinds of data races.  Without knowing more about the database technology in use, I imagine it would be safest to start with `SERIALIZABLE` transactions and perhaps downgrade to lower isolation levels if we can prove it is safe to do so.

Comment: How are races involved in the automatic deconflict interface handled? Cancellations? User closed that tab? etc.? Without full document locking, or fully-live docs (where each record is a session which all users join -- which, btw, your idea plus live docs is *absolutely awesome* but rarely implemented) this is very hard to do without introducing yet more races.

Comment: @zxq9: This is why we use the database.  There is *one* race: Who gets to the database first.  Everything else is irrelevant.  As for cancellations and closing the tab, I'll fix that in a moment.

Comment: Before there's a fight about it: I downvoted because I disagree with this proposition because of the complexity it will add to try to solve something easily done by a some comment talk or chat actually.

Comment: @Tensibai: This is a solved problem.  MediaWiki is open source.

Comment: @Kevin and StackOverflow is not a wiki and never aimed to be, it adds code complexity for a trivially fixed problem with a short human talk. I don't argue about the possibility to do it, I just think the problem does not worth it.

Comment: @Tensibai: SE already has most of the parts needed to implement something like MediaWiki-style edit conflict resolution. (Basically, the most complicated part is showing the difference between the two versions, and we already do that in history view / edit review.) We could argue about how user-friendly the way MediaWiki implements the feature (basically, showing two text boxes and a diff, and having the user copy-paste stuff between them) is, but I'd say almost *anything* is better than silently reverting the conflicting changes, like we do now.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I insist on the fact that it involves loading code for every edit on stackoverflow to deal with a small amount of conflict cases, the overhead does not worth it. Nothing is lost with actual system, and nothing prevent you (the one who see his/her edit is overwritten) to get in touch with the other editor in comments to agree on who will merge the two manually.

Comment: @Tensibai: Do you have any idea how much overhead that actually is?  I don't.

Comment: @Kevin that's not the matter, it IS an overhead, even if it is really small, it adds to load time, which if you look at all feature request is a major reason to decline if the usefulness is not proved/widely agreed. According to the votes on the Question, actually 9 people find it could be useful, that's low.

Comment: @Tensibai: Then let's remove the CSS.  Nobody needs that either.  Think of the bandwidth we'd save.

Comment: @Kevin slipping away on another subject because you don't like my point of view add nothing to this talk. I just give my point of view, that's the purpose of a Meta discussion... If you have no fact/evidence to support the claim an edit conflict resolution would improve the site because it happens on X% of edits, and X is high (how high ?) stop trying to convince me of it please. I just commented on the fact it will add an overhead in 100% of edits and there's nothing to prove it worth it actually, that's why I disagree with your position.

Comment: @Tensibai: The only overhead on "every edit" this would require is including the current post revision ID in the edit form and checking that it's still current when the edit is submitted. Everything else only needs to be loaded in the rare case when it doesn't. If even that tiny overhead mattered, SE could easily save *far* more bytes e.g. by stripping unnecessary whitespace from the HTML. (Besides, I just checked, and it seems that the current revision GUID is *already* included in the edit form. So, actually, the client-side overhead would be zero.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I quit. You seem not willing to understand. re "and checking that it's still current" This would add an overhead on server side also to get the current state and answer accordingly (as far as I can guess, the edit is just inserted as last in database actually)... Not talking on how you should react after this and what the presentation could be after that.

Comment: @Tensibai: Seeing as the Community user is already doing these rejections, ISTM the overhead is already present.  I'm just saying we need a better UI and no data races.

Comment: @Kevin Do you have a link about this behavior ? (U just remember the Community user endorsing a reject when the OP reject it but I may be wrong)

Comment: @Tensibai: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993/275243).

Comment: This is a different case which apply only to questions with edits made by users <2k, far less than all edits...

Comment: You know the post mentions two edits by 2K+ users? No suggested edits in sight. Also, how would you handle the grace-period?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm not sure how Stack Exchange handles the grace period.  If it internally assigns a new revision ID, then it's trivial.  Otherwise, you're in the nasty business of storing and comparing timestamps, which is never pleasant.  I suppose you could use a hash or checksum, but people will yell at me about "overhead" with that solution.

Comment: @Kevin: No, there's no hidden extra-revision-numbers. But SE sure could ad an additional version-field for posts still in grace-period...

Comment: @Deduplicator: I like that, but I'm sure someone will find a way to whine about how the table already has 37 columns and one more will somehow drive the site into the ground.  It's probably still better than trying to deal with timestamps.  [Time is evil](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY).

Comment: @Kevin: An extra table for posts edited within the last five minutes would be better. No need to store such longer.

Comment: In an effort to bring facts I played with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386203/potentially-conflicting-edits-in-last-n-days?LastNDays=90&WithinSeconds=30), I'm far from good in SQL so it could be totally wrong. The result I get is that there's around 25% of edits occurring withing 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

(Moved and expanded from a comment, on a dare.)

My understanding is that both commits should be accepted, the latest one takes precedence, overriding the other. Both are in the revision history. In what is essentially a wiki system this is much better than mysteriously rejecting the arbitrarily invalidated commit. They are both valid and neither should be discarded.

Consider: Abe opens edit, as does Brian. Abe goes to significant effort to fix layout/add citations/references/etc. while Brian spends a lot of effort adding totally new information. They commit at the same time. Should Abe's be rejected or Brian's?

The answer is "neither", though one will be the "latest" by virtue of having hit the db's commit queue last.

We lack the super-duper AI required to automatically merge arbitrary edits, so when one user gets a notification that "this post has been edited, click to load" the instant they hit "submit" and their edit isn't what is shown, it should be obvious that something weird is going on and the answer will be in the revision history. In the same way that manual voting, manual creation of content, and manual involvement in the electoral process are all necessary, this sort of weirdness will have to be manually de-funked as well.

Something to avoid doing is trying to play catch up in user interfaces by passing notifications which, if not adhered to, will lead to a *rejected* edit (the notices will arrive late, get lost, be off the edge of the screen on a user's phone, or for whatever other reason go unnoticed), especially in a web interface where it is very difficult to implement a document locking system (...if you think asynch edit commit races are bad...). Rejected data is lost data, and that is never the point. As rare as this case is, it would be truly horrible for someone to lose a high-quality, thoughtful edit because someone else thoughtfully corrected a semicolon at the same time.

The last thing we want to do is create an arbitrary *rejection* criteria that is invisible to the users involved.

Comment: "It should be obvious that something weird is going on" - No.  Don't rely on users spotting *anything*.  Users are lazy, distracted, non-programmers (not every SE is SO), in a hurry, etc.  *Some* users will be fortunate enough to notice.  Not all.

Comment: Devil's advocate: I know nothing about edit revisions, and I just see posts are edited. I make a substantial edit, like your Brian, adding new information. My edit is wiped by a somewhat trivial-seeming formatting edit. In order to make my changes stick, I have to make my edit _again_, on top of Abe's. Was my edit not originally arbitrarily rejected, in kind of an invisible way?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist actually no, you just have to roll-back to your revision, this add an entry in the edit history and reapply your edit, leaving the other in the history. In case of roll-back wars, a mod can called with a flag if really needed.

Comment: @Tensibai I'm not sure my fictitious "I know nothing about edit revisions" would know you could do that. _I_ didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Two well... If seing the edited by is a link is too hard... Ok, forget it, it seems I'm too confident in people intelligence

Comment: For previous comment. No offense intended, was a general feeling

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It is entirely possible that you don't understand what is going on. The revision history allows someone who *does* to fix it, even if it is not immediate. Edit commits occurring within a 10-second window is probably solid criteria for an auto-flag that indicates mod attention may be needed. My point is that if you don't know anything about revision editing then *why do we expect you to know what to do with a custom merge/deconflict interface when it suddenly pops up for the first time in your SE existence?*

Comment: @zxq9 No, I do get that. You just seem to me to be defending the status quo. However, to me, the status quo seems to a certain kind of user to be very much the sort of thing you're criticizing: an invisible, arbitrary rejection of their (good) contribution.