# How'd an empty edit make it into the revision history?

Tags: bug, edits, revision-history

Jongware and I both made an edit to remove an answer which had been included within a question.

He apparently had started editing about 15 seconds before me, but I had saved my edit before the notification appeared that an edit had been made to the post.

When I saw the notification and looked at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35086001/revisions), it shows my edit with no changes (since we both had removed the same text).

Is this some type of reader-writer problem where his edit didn't exist before mine was committed?

*Either way, I imagine this happens so infrequently, it wouldn't be worth fixing unless it happens to affect any integrity of the database.*

Comment: I also noticed that and wondered what exactly happened. Oh don't those pesky 1 in a million chances turn up 9 times out of 10!

Comment: Sorry, I used your question for an experiment... I just removed a newline, but it still shows edited text in the history. I thought it may be what happened in your case but clearly it's not that.

Comment: @Jongware Yep! And SO always refuses to do anything about it :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309508/1364007) to "[*Simultaneous editing (exact same timestamp) - no warning when overwriting other edit*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309441/1364007)" by [zxq9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/988678/zxq9):

> My understanding is that both commits should be accepted, the latest one takes precedence, overriding the other. Both are in the revision history. In what is essentially a wiki system this is much better than mysteriously rejecting the arbitrarily invalidated commit. They are both valid and neither should be discarded.

I think since you were both basing your edits on [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35086001/2) of the question, the system just overwrote the edit that Jongware made with yours. Since it was the same edit, no changes were present, but your revision was recorded nonetheless.

---

This is definitely **not** treated as though you were editing Jongware's revision ([revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35086001/3)) because, as you pointed out, there were no changes: even whitespace changes are eligible for side-by-side comparisons, as Lucas Trzesniewski's revision ([#3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/315837/revisions)) to your question shows. You can easily test this by trying to submit an edit with no changes (click "edit", then "Save edits") - since there *are* no changes, no revision is recorded.

---

This is also not treated as though changes were made and undone - see [revision 6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/315852/revisions) of this answer, which clearly says:

> [Edit removed during grace period]

---

I'll see if I can get two people on the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to coordinate edits to test this theory.

---

Update: I [asked on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28465958#28465958) and got a couple of replies which confirm this:

> [Wai Ha Lee](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1364007): Can I recruit two volunteers for a 2 minute experiment for [a meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315852/1364007)?
>
> [Tunaki](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki): @WaiHaLee No need. I confirm. It works like this. It seems to be recent change.
>
> ...
>
> [Sam](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2246344): @WaiHaLee Yeah, I've seen this happen a lot.