# Cross-editing a question results in undoing other editor work

Tags: discussion, edits

Not quite sure how did it happen, but I just made an edit that simply rolled back previous edit
[image: edition screen]
[link to revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35988990/revisions)

My theory, that I was editing simultaneously with @hjpotter92 after his "Rollback to revision 1", I am pretty sure that I did not see any warnings about editing old revision. Because my intention was to remove the part which I marked with green arrow. But timestamps show that we have at least half an hour between edits. So I am a little confused.
**My question are:**

1. How to prevent such situations, is there any way except reloading
       the page with the question and looking into revisions?
2. Shouldn't there be some kind of warning or something if I (low rep
   user)        undo others user (high rep) edit?

related question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309441/simultaneous-editing-exact-same-timestamp-no-warning-when-overwriting-other) but it suggests real simultaneous edits (which is not my case)